# Button opens Form

Tags: forms, delphi, button

My Problem is that I Wanted to create new Forms and Buttons with procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);. I had the problem that i did not know how to open the new created Forms with procedure TForm2.myClick(Sender: TObject);. I wanted that different forms are created by different buttons.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  procedure myClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
var
  i:Integer = 1;
var
  a:Integer = 1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TButton.Create(self) do begin
    Left := 80;
    Top := 50 + i * 60;
    Width := 300;
    Height := 50;
    Name := 'Liste' + IntToStr(i);
    Self.Caption := ClassName+' '+ IntToStr(i);
    OnClick := MyClick;
    Parent :=Form2;
  end;
  i:= i + 1;
  begin
          with TForm.Create(Self) do begin
                 Left := 0;
                 Top := 0;
                 Width := 1000;
                 Height := 700;
                 Name := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(a);
                 Caption := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(a);
                 Parent := self;
                 OnClick:= MyClick;
                 Visible:=false;
          end;
             a:= a + 1;
      end;
end;

procedure TForm2.myClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;




end.
```

Comment: I think you need to do some planning before you start coding. It is clear that you want your  `Form2` to have a button that, when clicked, creates other buttons. These buttons should, when clicked, create and show other kind(s) of form(s). Are these forms instances of design time designed form(s), or do you want to "design them in code" as your example shows? Are all of these secondary forms of the same type, or will you have different forms created by different buttons on `Form2`? Have you considered MDI? **But most important, and be clear on this, what exactly is your question?**

Comment: You're not keeping a reference when you create the form, which means there's no way to access it easily from the button click event. (You could iterate through `Screen.Forms` to try to find it, but you'd have to know exactly which form you're looking for ahead of time. Your design seems to be rather poor, but it's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish in order to suggest a better way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few number of unspecified items in your problem. Anyway, I made a simple example of what can be done. You'll get started and modify this code to suit your needs.

This code has a form (TForm1) with a single button. Each time the user click on the button, a new button and a new form are created. The created button is show on TForm1 in a column like you have done. The form is created but not visible like you have done. A list keep reference to the buttons and forms created.

The created button and form have their Tag property set to the index in the list. The button's OnClick event handler use this index to retrieve the corresponding form from the list and make it visible.

The form is created with a nil Parent so that it is a flying window. If you use Self instead of nil, the created form will be inside TForm1, much like an MDI application.

Here is the code:

```
unit DynFormDemoMain;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
    System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
    Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
    System.Generics.Collections;

type
    TFormItem = record
        AForm   : TForm;
        AButton : TButton;
    end;
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    private
        FList : TList<TFormItem>;
        procedure MyClick(Sender : TObject);
    public
        constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
        destructor Destroy; override;
    end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Item    : TFormItem;
    AButton : TButton;
    AForm   : TForm;
begin
    AButton         := TButton.Create(Self);
    AButton.Tag     := FList.Count;
    AButton.Left    := 80;
    AButton.Top     := 50 + AButton.Tag * 60;
    AButton.Width   := 300;
    AButton.Height  := 50;
    AButton.Name    := 'Liste' + IntToStr(AButton.Tag);
    AButton.Caption := ClassName + ' ' + IntToStr(AButton.Tag);
    AButton.OnClick := MyClick;
    AButton.Parent  := Self;

    AForm           := TForm.Create(Self);
    AForm.Tag       := AButton.Tag;
    AForm.Left      := AButton.Tag * 20;
    AForm.Top       := AButton.Tag * 20;
    AForm.Width     := 200;
    AForm.Height    := 100;
    AForm.Name      := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(AButton.Tag);
    AForm.Caption   := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(AButton.Tag);
    AForm.Parent    := nil;
    AForm.Visible   := FALSE;

    Item.AForm   := AForm;
    Item.AButton := AButton;
    FList.Add(Item);
end;

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited;
    FList := TList<TFormItem>.Create;
end;

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
    FreeAndNil(FList);
    inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    Item : TFormItem;
begin
    Item := FList[(Sender as TButton).Tag];
    if Assigned(Item.AForm) then
        Item.AForm.Show;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. It really helped me out.